# SQL Server : Group By causes "column invalid" error, how to solve that?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to filter `cg_group` names (please check the query) and group (using: `GROUP BY`) the results according to last updated opportunity (using: `ORDER BY opportunities.date_modified DESC`).

When I used query without use group by it returns the following results:

```
SELECT cg_groups.name
FROM cg_groups
JOIN cg_groups_cstm ON cg_groups_cstm.id_c = cg_groups.id
JOIN accounts_cstm ON cg_groups.name = accounts_cstm.client_group_c
JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c
JOIN accounts_opportunities ON accounts.id = accounts_opportunities.account_id
JOIN opportunities ON accounts_opportunities.opportunity_id = opportunities.id
WHERE cg_groups.deleted='0' AND cg_groups_cstm.status_c='1' AND opportunities.deleted='0' 
ORDER BY opportunities.date_modified DESC
```

Results:

```
ABC Group
ABC Group
CBC Group
ABC Group
XYZ Group
```

But I want to group this to following order:

```
ABC Group
CBC Group
XYZ Group
```

To do that I added `GROUP BY cg_groups.name`

```
SELECT cg_groups.name
FROM cg_groups
JOIN cg_groups_cstm ON cg_groups_cstm.id_c = cg_groups.id
JOIN accounts_cstm ON cg_groups.name = accounts_cstm.client_group_c
JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c
JOIN accounts_opportunities ON accounts.id = accounts_opportunities.account_id
JOIN opportunities ON accounts_opportunities.opportunity_id = opportunities.id
WHERE cg_groups.deleted='0' AND cg_groups_cstm.status_c='1' AND opportunities.deleted='0' 
GROUP BY cg_groups.name
ORDER BY opportunities.date_modified DESC
```

But now I get this error:

> Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Column "opportunities.date_modified" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Someone please help me to solve this issue, thank you.

Comment: You can't `order by` a value you aren't `grouping by`. Just as you can't select it. You'd need to aggregate it e.g. `min(date_modified)` but that might not be the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: If "abc group" contained two rows with dates = Jan 1 and Feb 1 before grouping, which one do you want to consider in the order by?

Answer (score 0):

put `opportunities.date_modified` in selection and group by then you can use that in order by

```
SELECT opportunities.date_modified,cg_groups.name
FROM cg_groups
JOIN cg_groups_cstm ON cg_groups_cstm.id_c = cg_groups.id
JOIN accounts_cstm ON cg_groups.name = accounts_cstm.client_group_c
JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c
JOIN accounts_opportunities ON accounts.id = accounts_opportunities.account_id
JOIN opportunities ON accounts_opportunities.opportunity_id = opportunities.id
WHERE cg_groups.deleted='0' AND cg_groups_cstm.status_c='1' AND opportunities.deleted='0' 
GROUP BY cg_groups.name,opportunities.date_modified
ORDER BY opportunities.date_modified DESC
```

but for your result you can try like below just use distinct

```
SELECT distinct cg_groups.name
FROM cg_groups
JOIN cg_groups_cstm ON cg_groups_cstm.id_c = cg_groups.id
JOIN accounts_cstm ON cg_groups.name = accounts_cstm.client_group_c
JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c
JOIN accounts_opportunities ON accounts.id = accounts_opportunities.account_id
JOIN opportunities ON accounts_opportunities.opportunity_id = opportunities.id
WHERE cg_groups.deleted='0' AND cg_groups_cstm.status_c='1' AND opportunities.deleted='0'
order by cg_groups.name
```

no group by need as you have not used any aggregate function

Comment: @DaleBurrell yes you are right 1st answer for error 2nd is for his desired result btw thanks

Comment: Your second query is not doing any ordering at all.  Are you sure this is what the OP wants?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to find the most recently updated record for each group:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT cg_groups.name, o.date_modified,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.date_modified DESC) rn
    FROM cg_groups cg
    INNER JOIN cg_groups_cstm cgc
        ON cgc.id_c = cg.id
    INNER JOIN accounts_cstm ac
       ON cg.name = ac.client_group_c
    INNER JOIN accounts a
       ON a.id = ac.id_c
    INNER JOIN accounts_opportunities ao
        ON a.id = ao.account_id
    INNER JOIN opportunities o
        ON ao.opportunity_id = o.id
    WHERE cg.deleted = '0' AND cgc.status_c = '1' AND o.deleted = '0'
)

SELECT name
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY date_modified DESC;
```

Note that this may not be exactly what you want.  This answer returns a single record per name group which is the most recently updated for that group.  It then orders all results descending, but maybe you want ascending.

Answer (score 0):

how about just adding `distinct` right after your `SELECT` statement .

```
Select distinct ... from ...
```